# transfer Data from local database and server Database

Tags: database

i have desktop application for point of sales and have two servers one in local and another on live server.

The database in local is sql express and on server sql enterprise,so i can not  use replication.

i have two possible  solutions:

- Create Windows Task Scheduler runs sql commands
- create timer in my desktop application to run sql command every hours

what the best solution  to transfer  Date from to server?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler. Why would you want to code an app when you can use Windows Task Scheduler ?

Comment: there two reason , i must Create Task Scheduler at 40 Shops,Second, shop may Disable Or delete Task Scheduler (security)

Comment: Forget #2. If they are going to be malicious, they will get around anything that you do.